# Data length module of 3.2^n confusion in IBM system/360 architecture

Tags: mainframe, architecture, early-computer, s360

I'm currently reading about the [IBM system/360 architecture](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220498837_Architecture_of_the_IBM_System360) and there's a part that has me very confused:

> The decision on basic format (which affected character size, word size, instruction field, number of index registers, input-output implementation, instruction set layout, storage capacity, character code, etc.) was whether data length modules should go as 2<sup>n</sup> or 3.2<sup>n</sup>.

Why would a data length module would be 3.2<sup>n</sup>?

Comment: What is a "data length module?"  I think I know what it is from context, but I've never heard this term before and wonder if it's an S/360 specific term, or a typo.

Comment: @WayneConrad I'm in the same boat as you. I hope I will understand better as I keep reading the paper.

Comment: Can you point us to what you're actually reading?

Comment: The extract is from the 1964 paper [*Architecture of the IBM System/360*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220498837_Architecture_of_the_IBM_System360) by Amdahl, Blaauw, and Brooks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that 3.2 is the square root of 10 rounded up to the closest value with one digit after the decimal.

Thus, every other data length module will be slightly greater than a power of 10. Apparently there was an expectation that data block lengths will be typically close to powers of 10, achieving good capacity utilization, while providing acceptable intermediate sizes for other block lengths.

The values of 3.2<sup>n</sup>, rounded to the nearest integer, are 3, 10, 33, 105, 336, 1074, ...

Comment: It might be useful to add that at that time decimal based computers were still a thing in 1960. This meant not only decimal arithmetic instead of binary, but decimal addressing as well as block sizes of 10/100/1000. So making the /360 strictly binary (and BCD just an optional user data type) in all details (4/8/16/32 bit units, 12/24 bit addressing, 2048/4096 byte data blocks etc.)  war quite revolutionary - next to all machines before were a mixup of different based elements.

Comment: @Raffzahn - correct, and in that timeframe even _the size of "blocks" on the disk wasn't defined as a power of 2_ - in fact, disks weren't even divided into "blocks".  You could write records of any length at all (as long as it would fit in a "track").  So there was quite a bit of flexibility available to the designers.

Comment: (Oddly enough, w.r.t. to disks, we now have our feet firmly planted on both sides of the divide: we read/write in chunks of powers of 2 but we purchase in chunks of powers of 10!)

Comment: If the explanation for that section was that data block sizes were expected to be close to a power of 10, wouldn't the author have characterized the decision as 2^n versus 10^n?

Comment: @davidbak Everything is really still powers of 2. It is the marketing people who want to smush things into powers of 10 because that way instead of 1,024 x 1,024 = 1,048,576 = 1 Meg., instead 1,000,000 = 1 Meg. Which is more like 1,024 x 976 - so they can give us 4 % (more actually as you get to Gigabyte, Terabyte) and make it sound like "the real thing". In the end it matters little because (a) the manufacturers copy each other and (b) as long as storage keeps getting cheaper, a few % doesn't matter much. But the blocks are not suddenly 1,000 bytes or 10,000 bytes etc.

Comment: I think 3.2^n should be read 3 times 2 to the power n, making this answer irrelevant.

Answer (score 11):

The notation 3.2<sup>n</sup>  looks to me like it means 3 x 2<sup>n</sup> rather than (3 point 2)<sup>n</sup>.

So the question is whether data lengths should be based on a 6-bit unit or some 'binary' size, in practice 8 bits.

The dominant character size at the time was 6 bits (with 7-bit ASCII just emerging).  A 36-bit word length was also common, and was in fact the word size for the successful 709/7090/7094 family.

There were definitely arguments made for keeping a 6-bit size to 'save storage'.

I do not have an authoritative reference to hand, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360#Influential_features) notes that one influential S/360 feature was:

> The 8-bit byte (against financial pressure during development to
>   reduce the byte to 4 or 6 bits), rather than adopting the 7030 concept
>   of accessing bytes of variable size at arbitrary bit addresses.

---

Aha, per Fred Brooks:  [see page 25](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2012/11/102658255-05-01-acc.pdf)

> There was one very big difference, and that is Gene’s machine was
>   based on the six-bit byte and multiples of that so 24-bit
>   instructions, 48-bit floating part  and Jerry’s machine was
>   based on a 8-bit byte and 32-bit instructions, 64-bit, and 32-bit
>   floating point, which is not a real happy choice, but… there are
>   strong arguments each way. And you want your architects to be
>   consistent. You’re not going to have an 8-bit byte and 48-bit
>   instruction floating point word. And, so, then came the biggest
>   internal fight, and that was between the six and eight bit byte, and
>   that story has been told. Gene and I each quit once that week, quit
>   the company, and Manny

(Gene is Amdahl, Jerry is Blaauw)

24 is 3 x 2<sup>3</sup>, 48 is 3 x 2<sup>4</sup>.

---

Futhermore:

The extract in the question comes from a 1964 IBM Journal paper  [*Architecture of the IBM System/360*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220498837_Architecture_of_the_IBM_System360), by Amdahl, Blaauw, and Brooks.  The quoted text is on page 91 of the journal, or 4 or 5 pages into the paper.

The extract is immediately followed by a discussion of character sizes (6 versus 8 bits) and floating-point operand sizes (48 versus 32/64 bits).  This makes it clear that  3.2<sup>n</sup> is to be understood as 3 x 2<sup>n</sup>.

Maybe we can blame the compositor for setting 3.2<sup>n</sup> rather than 3·2<sup>n</sup>.